# Im unable to reload the list data when I click on button using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

step1: Initially while page load $scope.results is empty arrayList

step2: When I click on search button I am unbale to load the data in table

### 1) test.js

While page loading results is empty

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http','$location', '$rootScope', 'DataService','SearchService',
    function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, DataService,SearchService) { 

    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.searchSubmit = function(){
            $scope.dashboardflag = true;
            $("#dashboard").hide();
            SearchService.getSearchResults.query({searchText:$scope.searchText,
                startDate:$("#startDate").val(),endDate:$("#endDate").val(),
                userId:$scope.userEntity.userid,managerId:101083,
                status:'Answered',threadType:'REPLY',
                pageNumber:0
                },function(data) {
                    //var data1 = data.list;
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.results = angular.copy(data);
                    });

            });
            $("#searchResults").show();
        };
}]);
```

### 2) test.html

Search

```
    <table id="searchObjResults" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Assignto</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Workflow</th>
            <th>Assignment date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in results">
            <td>{{obj.userName}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.threadTitle}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.threadId}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.threadStatus}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.threadType}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.assignedDate}}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the result in data after http call?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Does `data` contain anything when you inspect it? Also we can't see where you bind your button or what the scope of your controller is.

Comment: You're really, really doing it wrong. Stop doing DOM manipulation in controllers. Use AngularJS as you should, instead of using it as you would use a jQuery plugin. And check the order of your injected services.

Comment: If you are sure that you get the results in data after http call, make sure you are using right variable name in html. Because angularjs is case sensitive.. UserName is different from userName..

Comment: Just a tip: for those startDate and endDate values you are getting using jquery, you should probably be using the angular `ng-model` instead. The jquery you are using for ".show()" and ".hide()" can also be done using angular with the `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives

Comment: Here i'm not rendering data to html page

Comment: you no need to load data to html. Angularjs is smart enough to handle this. In inspect element check whether you've array of objects and the naming conventions and object property. so the data will be loaded in table (This is actually rendering data in html)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things,
first if you already posted you html, please post the full html, 
where is the ng-app, and your controller?
second, if you want to show\hide elemets maybe you should concider using ng-hide and add a some var to the scope that wlil control that 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide
also, is the "data" returning from the sevice is an array?
please console.log the result, for more info

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. It may help you to follow. If no data found, then table will not be shown to the user.

Refer: http://plnkr.co/edit/blSWT4eowYv17UwwhcnQ?p=preview

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
      <table id="searchObjResults" border="1" ng-show="results.length">
        <tr>
            <th>Assignto</th>
            <th>Title</th>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in results">
            <td>{{obj.userName}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.threadTitle}}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.data = [{
      userName: 'username1',
      threadTitle: 'threadTitle1'
    }, {
      userName: 'username2',
      threadTitle: 'threadTitle2'
    }];
    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.results = angular.copy($scope.data);
    }
  });
```